# Laravel won't route on production server

Tags: laravel, apache2, debian, laravel-5, homestead

Just getting started with laravel and have run into some trouble.

Before committing to using laravel I wanted to build a very basic web app to test the waters via homestead and then move that web app to a remote server in order to see how easy the process was.

So I've got homestead up and running and have built a very basic web app and it works perfectly locally.

However when I moved the laravel project onto the remote server the routing stopped working.

For example locally testProject.dev/contact takes me through to a mock 'contact us' view. However when I try that on productionServer.com/contact I'm greeted by a 403 'you do not have permission to access contact on this server'.

Am I missing something in laravel here or is this an issue with the sever setup?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This looks like a file permissions problem. Make sure the app files on the server have the correct permissions so they can be read by the HTTP server (and where needed the permissions also to allow writing, like the `storage` directory for example).

Comment: I thought this also, I've given the entire directory 777 recursively to test and the same thing happens. Is there some other permission I'm missing?

Comment: What HTTP server are you using in production? I suspect this to be pretty URLs problem, take a look at this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#pretty-urls

Comment: Ah, just had a read of that, sounds like it could be the issue. I'll take a look in the morning. Thanks very much.

Comment: This also didn't work. Any more ideas? Really can't work out whats going on here.

Comment: So which HTTP server are you using? Nginx, Apache?

Comment: Apache, I'm starting to think this is a mod_security issue. Lots of errors in the logs about changes to URL triggering 403.

Answer (score 0):

Update -> This turned out to be an issue with another piece of software running on the server. Thanks for all the help.